# What Flash can do that HTML5 not?

Tags: flash, html

What things Flash can do that aren't possible with HTML5 currently?

For example, Flash supports raw access to the underlying network, while WebSocket needs some proxy server. This one is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of reasons of what Flash offers over HTML5 regarding video http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/06/flash-and-html5-tag.html

Answer (score 1):

Among other things flash can bring C/C++ libraries to the web using Adobe Alchemy

Answer (score 1):

Work on almost every browser (except iphone:)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I should also mention that Flash currently outperforms HTML5, so in that regard it would also limit what can be achieved with HTML5 currently - although I am keeping an eye on WebGL to see how well that can be leveraged.

http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2010/03/22/