# What does HTML5 offer over Adobe Technologies?

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html5 vs flash - full comparison chart anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628565/html5-vs-flash-full-comparison-chart-anywhere)

What I mean is, assume I have a Flex application, with Java at server end. I have .mxml pages and .as for object based approach. They are now saying that HTML5 poses a serious threat to Adobe, Microsoft Technologies. Is it possible to convert my application to HTML5 based ? If so, please explain or post a link for head-to-head example comparison. I know HTML5 is lighter and has new UI components that rival Flex but I want it in terms of entire web application.

Comment: A quick search on SO reveals a bunch of similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172626/how-can-html5-replace-flash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628565/html5-vs-flash-full-comparison-chart-anywhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059450/silverlight-vs-flash-vs-html5-should-i-care http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990845/html5-or-flash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681411/does-html5-only-replace-the-video-aspects-of-flash-silverlight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377071/what-flash-can-do-that-html5-not